# How to use one XCTestCase class for many targets

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xcode-server, xctestcase

I have white label project (many app's on one source code). Usually I reuse one ViewController for many targets, but to test this ViewController in different targets I must add:
    @testable import TargetName

I have tried to create Swift Compiler - Custom Flag with:

1. -D TARGET_TEST1
2. -D TARGET_TEST2

and use:

```
//
#if TARGET_TEST1
@testable import TARGET_TEST1
#else
@testable import TARGET_TEST2
#endif
//
```

For testing in Xcode it's work, but if I start this on Xcode Server, I have error:

> Use of undeclared type 'NameOfClass.swift'

Is it any other options how to provide @testable import for specific test target?

Comment: Have you tried using the swift compiler function `canImport`? If each of your modules has a unique name, than you can try:
```
#if canImport(Module1)
import Module1
#elseif canImport(Module2)
import Module2
#endif
```
Than you wouldn't need to depend on custom flags.